# add Qt to existing Visual Studio c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I've got an existing Visual Studio C++ project. It creates a main window using GLUT and also uses glut for a right-click context menu.

All I want to do now, is to open a second window used as a property inspector to display and change some values.

Everyone recommends using Qt for GUI development, but all the tutorials I find discuss either working in Qt creator or how to create a Qt project from scratch.

I have used Qt some years ago to do something similar and it was not so difficult to add it to my project.

Can anyone explain, or point me to a tutorial explaining how to do this?

thanks!

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, you should probably just use WPF.

Comment: WPF is .Net no? It's a c++ project i'm working on

Comment: Oh, you just say Visual Studio, so I assume it's a .NET project.

Comment: I just want a headache-free way to add a very simple graphical userinput to a working c++ application

Comment: The problem is that you don't  know how to build your widget without QtCreator ?

Answer (score 12):

Thank to Arno Duvenhage and Tom for their answers. Here are steps who worked for me in Qt 5.2.1 and Visual Studio 2012 and 2015:

1. Install QT Add In (for visual studio 2015 is in still in beta, but works fully for me).
2. Right click the project, select "Unload project".
3. Add  add the `<keyword>Qt4VSv1.0</keyword>` entry into the `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` tag.
4. Select load project.
5. Select "Convert project to Qt Add-in project" in "Qt 5" menu.
6. Almost done. Go to Qt project settings and Qt option in the Qt menu to set details.
7. In your project properties Linker\Additional Library Directories\ might need to add $(QTDIR)\lib
8. In your project properties C++\Additional Include Directories\ might need to add $(QTDIR)\include
9. In each of your classes derived from Q_OBJECT, delete the Q_OBJECT macro, save the file, return the Q_OBJECT macro (Ctrl+Z), and save again. It adds the 'moc' files to your generated files folder.
10. Set your project as startup project.

Answer (score 5):

edit your project using an xml editor

i usually unload the project, right click on it and select edit

add the qt version you wish to use (for me it's):

```
Keyword="Qt4VSv1.0"
```

and the following globals

```
        <Global
        Name="lupdateOnBuild"
        Value="0"
    />
    <Global
        Name="MocDir"
        Value=".\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName)"
    />
    <Global
        Name="MocOptions"
        Value=""
    />
    <Global
        Name="QtVersion Win32"
        Value="QT 4.5.3"
    />
    <Global
        Name="RccDir"
        Value=".\GeneratedFiles"
    />
    <Global
        Name="UicDir"
        Value=".\GeneratedFiles"
    />
```

reload the project and fiddle with "convert project to QMake generated project" and it should work

Comment: the globals didn't work for me. But adding the keyword and setting these configs on property pages did.

Comment: This worked for me with Qt 5.9.9 and Visual studio 2019. "convert project to QMake generated project" is located in the file menu under Extensions->QT VS Tools or by Right-clicking on the project -> Qt

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

- manually change the project version to a qt project in the project file -- use `<Keyword>Qt4VSv1.0</Keyword>'`
- reload the project
- right click on the project and select 'update to a qt-addin project'
- remove and add the qt source files to the project

Hope it helps.

Comment: To be more precise add the <keyword>Qt4VSv1.0</keyword> entry into the <PropertyGroup Label="Globals"> tag. Then select

Answer (score -4):

There is an ability of qmake to generate .vcproj from a .pro file. So you should read qmake documentation to create a right .pro file.