# How could i add qt to my existing vs 2019 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt6, qt-vs-addin

I tried [add Qt to existing Visual Studio c++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028604/add-qt-to-existing-visual-studio-c-project) but I can't find "Convert project to Qt Add-in project" button nowhere. I added the keyword and the globals but when I right click the project qt doesn't appear. I use qt 6.2.2 and the latest qt addon for vs 2019

Comment: I use qt 6.2.2 and the latest qt addon for vs 2019

Comment: Thanks for the additional information,. I updated the question and tags to make it more clear. While I do use Qt with Visual Studio 2019, I don't use the addon so I can't help. I am hoping with the additional information someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks! ive been dealing with this mess for a couple of days now :/